# Returning Whether Dictionary or Array from function?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift2, return-type

I have an global function that returns parameters, headers and url for http requests. Though headers and url will always be the same type, parameters won't. It depends on request.`[[String:String]]` or `[String: Any]`. I tried to make the func generic, but i didn't work because I have to make processes and they are not always conform with these types. There is switch a in my function and in the some of the cases i should use arrayType and at the other ones i should use dictionaryType for the `parameter` and then return it. So here is the question; how can I define the `parameter` ?  Or what can I do?

Any suggestion will make me so appreciated.

I tried to write an struct that will make me able to decide to type of parameter like this;

```
struct parameterType<KeyType: Hashable, ValueType>{
    typealias arrayType = [[String:String]]
    typealias dictionaryType = [String: Any]
}
```

But I couldn't figure out how can I use it.

These is the function;

```
private func returnStaticDataForPostRequest<parameterType>(requestType: postRequestType, additionalParameters: [AnyObject]?) -> (url:NSURL, header:[String: String], parameter: [String: AnyObject]){}
```

Parameter in the function's return state sometimes should be `[String: AnyObject]` not `[String: Any]`

Again any help would make me so happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know about `Endpoints`? It's abstract layer for configuration of network request parameters like URL, parameters, method and others. You can write base protocol with default implementation, for example:

```
protocol Endpoint {

    var baseURL: String { get }
    var path: String { get }
    var headers: [RequestHeaders] { get }
    var parameters: Parameters { get }
    var requiresAuthorizationHeaders: Bool { get }
}

extension Endpoint {

    var baseURL: String {
        return "http://google.com"
    }

    var headers: [RequestHeaders] {
        switch self {
        default: return []
        }
    }

    var requiresAuthorizationHeaders: Bool {
        return true
    }

    var parameterEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
        return URLEncoding.default
    }
}
```

Then you need to create endpoint for every request in your application and override property if needed. For your requests you need to write method like that:

```
private func request(endpoint: RequestEndpoint) -> DataRequest {
    let headers = self.headers(for: endpoint)
    return Alamofire.request(URLForEndpoint(endpoint),
                             method: endpoint.method,
                             parameters: endpoint.parameters,
                             encoding: endpoint.parameterEncoding,
                             headers: headers)
}
```

You can read more about this approach in [Moya](https://github.com/Moya/Moya) framework repo, it uses same technique for requests.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an enum with associated values as part of the return value. For example you could use:

```
enum ParameterTypeEnum {
    case Dictionary(value: [String: Any])
    case Array(value: [[String:String]])
}
```

You would have a switch statement to extract the parameters and use them as you need. I found [this](http://appventure.me/2015/10/17/advanced-practical-enum-examples/#basicexamples) website to be really useful in finding out what you can do with enums.

Comment: I've thought about your answer a little bit. I have already have a switch condition. If I use one more I have to use it every case in main switch. There should be a better, efficient way.